# Paging on ADX table. how to skip the records in kusto query language

Tags: azure, kql, adx

I want to implement paging on ADX  table (kql) like offset, fetch next some rows only we generally do in SQL Server, but I am unable to skip/offset option in kusto query lang. is there any alternative to achieve paging on ADX table records.

Please provide an alternative solution for applying paging on ADX Table records without using row_number().

we have | take or | limit options, looking for an option that skips the records.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the example in the documentation, using stored query results: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/stored-query-results#pagination